# log steps of the tests in Ide Intelij

Tags: selenium-webdriver, logs

Is it possible to log steps of the tests that are being executed in the Intelij console??? could someone let me know?

some command or plugin that I must install to visualize the steps while I run my tests.

[image]

Comment: your question is not really clear. we need more details to suggest something useful. 
Maybe simple debugging and break points will help you? or you want to add logs for your test automation steps? if 2nd it will require code changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just learning, and it's java or similar, something like `System.out.println("mesg");` for regular outputs,

for more on the output channels and their use maybe look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163399/difference-between-system-out-println-and-system-err-println

You may also want to look at the IDE's debugging features, and step through logic where you can inspect all sorts of things about the state at each step.

I would guess some time invested in some coding course(s) and review of the IDE features would be beneficial...